# What is the technical purpose of using next keyword and empty method to terminate an each loop?

Tags: ruby, methods, block, is-empty

I was flipping through an basic ruby textbook and I came across a piece of code that serves as an introduction to ruby blocks.

```
letters = ("a".."c").to_a
```

The example iterates through the array:

```
letters.each { |letter| next if letter.empty? } #example 1
```

This seemed counter intuitive to me because I would do:

```
letters.each { |letter| } #example 2
```

I also experimented with:

```
letters.each { |letter| next if letters.empty? }  #example 3
```

All the examples gave me the same output in irb for alpha characters.

I tested the book example with numbers which kicked back an error, which makes sense to me.

```
nums.each { |n| next if n.empty? } # NameError
```

So my question is: **Why use `next if item.empty?` to terminate an each loop?**

Comment: Which book are you flipping through? Example 1 does not make any sense since nothing is happening inside the loop.

Comment: Your example 4 is failing because numbers don't implement `.empty?` and should throw `NoMethodError`.
You will get `NameError` in case your variable `nums` is not defined.

Comment: outside of this example `next` is pretty useful in loops because it lets you to skip loop's iteration for some values.

Comment: `each` with a block always returns its receiver (e.g., `["a", "b", "c"]`) unless there is a premature exist from the block, such as `break 'cat'` or `return 'cat'`. In Example 1 `letter` is never empty. If `letters = ["a", "", "c"]`, then when `letter #=> ""`, `letter.empty? #=> true`, so `next` is executed, but it has no effect because there are no statements to skip over. Here `letters.each { |letter| next if letter.empty? } #=> ["a", "", "c"]`. I find this all very strange and don't know the point of the author's examples. My advice is to put this, and possibly the book, out of your mind.

Comment: More tags is not better than fewer tags. Might someone search on "ruby", Yes, of course. Might someone search on any of the other tags? I doubt it. I would have just one tag here: "ruby".

Comment: @Olkin the book is "Ruby Wizardry", p.57. I know what `next` does in general - I find it merely odd in the book's example. As for `nums`:  I was testing if integers behaved differently.  `nums = (0..2).to_a; nums.each { |n| next if nums.empty?}` and `nums.each { |n| }` give me the same output.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I was aiming to be very specific, hence the overkill with the tags. Your point is well taken. I was concerned about appeasing and not getting downvoted.  Overall, just trying to understand the author's intents.  Often intro coding books *are* more important than advanced books - noobs won't get to the advanced ruby books if the intro books fail to entice or make sense.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I imagine your explanation is implicitly what the author went for with the example.  However, in an educational book, it should have been stated *explicilty* with an `""` value in `letters` array.  As it stands, it gives the impression that `next if item.empty?` is part and parcel of an `each` loop.  It is not.

Comment: @foo, as mentioned by @CarySwoveland `each` will always return its receiver. So in both cases for `nums` example it will always return array `nums`. And it will return `letters` array in your `letters` examples.
However if you  do `nums.each { |n| next if n.empty? }` it will return `NoMethodError`. It seems pretty close to another example you provided in comments. `nums.each { |n| next if nums.empty? }` will just return `nums` without exception because you call `.empy?` on `nums` (array) instead of `n`(element of array).

Comment: I'll try to find the book and maybe will understand more what author was trying to explain. So far I don't see any educational point in these examples. And it's awesome  that you're trying to understand!

Comment: I found the book. At least page 57. 
I think they are focusing more on syntax and not what that loop was doing. That chapter explains how they converted `for/in` syntax into using `each`. However I don't know why they didn't use the same loop body. E.g. it will make more sense if they at least printed something inside the loop. But then it's trickier to put all that in 1-liner, but they really wanted to show how to use curly braces `{}` instead of `do/end`.